# VBA. Dynamic column

Tags: excel, vba

I need to fulfill a table by a loop, so the number of a column needs to be changing.

I have tried two options:

z is from 1 to 4

1. `Sheets("Annex").Range("E3:H101").Column(Z) = Sheets("Calc").Range("I2:I100")`
2. `Sheets("Annex").Range(Cells(3,z+4),Cells(101,z+4)) = Sheets("Calc").Range("I2:I100")`

However, nothing worked.
Could you help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Instead of saying "nothing worked" please describe what happens , including any error messages - and show your code in the context of the loop

Comment: Starter for 10 - `Sheets("Annex").Range("E3:H101").Column(Z)` will generate an error. That should be `Sheets("Annex").Range("E3:H101").Columns(Z)`

Comment: Use `.Value` on both ranges.

Comment: @CHill60 Thank you! I have tried the following: Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Z = 1
Sheets("Annex").Range("E3:H101").Columns(Z).Value = Sheets("Calc").Range("I2:I100").Value

End Sub
I have got the error: "Run-time error 9. Subscript out of range"

Comment: Are your sheet names correct? I just copied your code, hit a couple of enters and ran the code just fine after creating a sheet called "Annex" and another one called "Calc".

Comment: @Notus_Panda, thank you very much! Yes, sheets are correct. Now it has worked. I do not know, perhaps, there was a bug yesterday preventing its execution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to copy data to the Annex sheet from column I in the Calc sheet. I would use a loop like below.

```
For z = 1 To 4
    Dim toRange As Range
    Set toRange = Sheets("Annex").Cells(3, z + 4).Resize(99, 1)
    toRange.Value = Sheets("Calc").Range("I2:I100").Value
Next z
```